# Swift : get all installed application and open specific one

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, url-scheme

Is there any way to get all the list of installed application and check a specific bundle/app can be open which is already installed in swift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only open an app if you know its URL Scheme just like facebook provides for example. `fb://`

There is no way to get the list of applications. Can't say anything about jail broken devices.